# How to search for word in array

Tags: bash

I have an array

```
array=("a b" "c d")
```

Now I have to search for `a b` and find occurrence. How to approach?

Comment: In bash? I don't thinks there's a way other than iterating over the elements and testing them for equality one by one. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes I tried the same. But it is searching for "a" and then "b", not as "a b".

Comment: @Anony what exactly did you try? And why do you need to do this?

Comment: Also, have you searched at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366390/check-if-an-element-is-present-in-a-bash-array, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177138/how-do-i-test-if-an-item-is-in-a-bash-array  https://superuser.com/questions/195598/test-if-element-is-in-array-in-bash

Answer (score 6):

When you [print your array elements each on a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691942/bash-print-array-elements-on-separate-lines), you can use grep:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep "a b"
```

If array elements contain `\n`, it's better to use `\0` and `grep -z` *(thanks @muru)*:

```
printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | grep -z "a b"
```

Comment: Consider using `\0` and `grep -z` instead

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
array=("a b" "c d")

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
  if [[ ${array[$i]} == "a b" ]]; then
    echo "Element $i matched"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
Element 0 matched
```

`${#array[@]}` contains number of last element in array.

Comment: You can also do `for i in "${!array[@]}"` to directly get the array indices, which will handle missing indices and associative arrays without problems.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394738/5088142) suggest a way to perform the search

Implementation for your question:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=("a b" "c d")
value="a b"
if [[ " ${array[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]]; then
   echo found $value
fi
```

Output:

```
found a b
```

Comment: OK but note the comment below the SO answer *"Not a good strategy if your fields contain spaces."* - for example it will "match" if `array=("a a" "b b")` I think?

Answer (score 0):

A variant on Cyrus's answer in function form:

```bash
function find_in_array() {
    local needle="$1"
    shift
    local haystack=("$@")
    for ((i=0; i<${#haystack[@]}; i++)); do
      if [[ ${haystack[$i]} == "$needle" ]]; then
        echo $i
      fi
    done
}
```

This prints the index of the first position of the needle in the haystack array, and nothing if the needle is not found.